# Cannot display texts in front of video background with BigVideo.js plugin in Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails app where I'd like to render a video background using BigVideo.js. However, I can only get the video to show up in front of everything else, so it defeats the purpose of being a background.

Here is my code:

layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.7/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.7/video.js"></script>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

assets/javascripts/static.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var BV = new $.BigVideo({container: $('.wrapper')});
  BV.init();
  BV.show('http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4',{ambient:true});
});
```

views/static/index.html.erb:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='jumbotron'>
    <h2 class='center-text'>I'd like to show up in front of the video</h2>
    <div class="wrapper"></div>

    <div class="text-center">
      <a class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' role='button'>Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help or pointers!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I didn't set a z-index on my video-background. It worked once I set a z-index of -1.